# microsoft_graph oAuth refresh error

Tags: oauth, office365, omniauth, microsoft-graph-api

I allow users to authorize their Microsoft accounts using oAuth and the Microsoft Graph API. I am using [this omniauth strategy](https://github.com/synth/omniauth-microsoft_graph) to facilitate the authorization. In the OmniAuth strategy, it includes the resource for both `authorize_params` and `token_params` "https://graph.microsoft.com". This allows me to authenticate just fine but when I go to refresh the auth, I get this error returned:

```
{"error"=>"unauthorized_client", "error_description"=>"AADSTS70001: Resource 'https://graph.microsoft.com/' is not supported as resource.\r\n"}
```

Along with a trace_id and some other things that I will post if needed.

The endpoint I am hitting to refresh is `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` with the `client_id`, `refresh_token` and `grant_type: "refresh_token"` params.

Refreshing this oAuth token was working fine as recently as last week. Did something change with the Microsoft Graph API or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Refreshing a Token](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/#refreshing-a-token).

It sounds like you were partially there, you were just missing some additional parameters:

- grant_type - Set as `refresh_token`
- refresh_token - The refresh token value you received from the Provider
- client_id - This is your Application ID from above
- client_secret - This is the Password we generated before
- scope - This should match the same set of scopes you first requested
- redirect_uri - This is the redirect URI defined in your application registration

These are formatted `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in you POST to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`

```
POST URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
POST HEADER: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
POST BODY: grant_type=refresh_token&amp;refresh_token=[REFRESH TOKEN]
           &amp;client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&amp;client_secret=[PASSWORD]
           &amp;scope=[SCOPE]&amp;redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was as simple as I was authing to `v1.0` but attempting to reauth to `v2.0`. Not sure why this worked up until now but ensuring they are hitting the same version of the API has solved the issue.